CTest: Test not available without configuration
I realize this is a very basic question, but I was unable to fix my problem despite even after reading multiple tutorials, including the official tutorial and the Professional Cmake book.
I am simply trying to add unit tests to my C++ project with CMake 3.28 on Visual Studio 2022. However, when I run CTest, I get the following error:
Test not available without configuration.  (Missing "-C <config>"?)
1/1 Test #1: cpp_test .........................***Not Run   0.00 sec

The "Test not available without configuration" message seems to indicate the configuration is missing. I did however defined the test in my CMakeLists.txt.
I recreated the problem with minimal code.
main.ccp
int main()
{
    return 0;
}

cpp_test.cpp
int main()
{
    return 0;
}

CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28.0)

project("myproject")

add_executable (CMakeProject1 "main.cpp")

add_executable(cpp_test cpp_test.cpp)
enable_testing()
add_test(NAME cpp_test COMMAND $<TARGET_FILE:cpp_test>)

All files are located in the same folder.
When I run the following commands:
cmake -S . -B build
cd build
cmake --build .
ctest . --rerun-failed --output-on-failure

I get the error:
Test project C:/Users/…/source/repos/CMakeProject1/CMakeProject1/build
    Start 1: cpp_test
Test not available without configuration.  (Missing "-C <config>"?)
1/1 Test #1: cpp_test .........................***Not Run   0.00 sec

0% tests passed, 1 tests failed out of 1

Total Test time (real) =   0.02 sec

The following tests FAILED:
          1 - cpp_test (Not Run)
Errors while running CTest


I wonder what cmake build . would do. Do you mean cmake --build . instead? The path C:/Users/…/source/repos/CMakeProject1/CMakeProject1/build with duplicated component CMakeProject1/ smells too. May be, you are running not the project which you have built?

@Tsyvarev It is a non-standard alternative to --build that I shouldn’t use, I corrected this. The fact CMakeProject1 is duplicated is because I originally created this project from the VS template which creates a folder for the solution, and for the project(s) inside. But I ran all my commands from the project folder (i.e. the sub-folder).

Eh? Now your commands list doesn't contain a building command at all.

BTW, the error message is about -C option for ctest executable which denotes name of the configuration you want to test: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/ctest.1.html#cmdoption-ctest-C

@Tsyvarev Okay, I put back cmake --build ., I wrongly assumed it was part of cmake -B.

@Tsyvarev You’re right, I had to add "Debug". I was confused as my CMakeLists.txt file does not define any specific configuration, and the documentation only mentions the -C command for specific projects that "have multiple build configurations in the same tree", so I thought it did not apply to my project. But apparently, the cmake --build . (or cmake -B) defines the Debug and Release configurations automatically.

May be, related: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/20283. As far as I understand from that issue, in case of multiconfiguration generator (like Visual Studio is) plain ctest is able to work with "default configuration" (whatever this mean). But some ctest parameters may require to specify configuration explicitly.

As @Tsyvarev mentioned in the comments, a configuration is required when using multi-configuration generators like Visual Studio. In that case, add the configuration you want the test to run in (.e.g -C Debug)
